# How can I make Gnome pass the super key to desktop viewers?

Tags: gnome, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, gnome-shell, remmina

TLDR: Gnome always eats the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.  How can I make it stop for certain applications?

**Long version:**

I'm running 18.04, but this has been an issue for about five years, and I'm sufficiently fed up to try to solve it.

I spend a lot of time focussed on non-physical machines.  Sometimes this is through a VM viewer like looking-glass, virt-viewer, and virtualbox (although sometimes it works correctly).  Sometimes I'm accessing a non-local machine through a remote desktop viewer like remmina, rdesktop, or vncviewer.

When any one of those viewer applications is focussed (particularly when it's fullscreened), I want *every key event* passed to it, with a small list of exceptions: grab release/hostkey, multimedia, and my desktop switch hotkeys.

How can I contextually prevent Gnome from eating keystrokes that I want to be passed to my applications?

Comment: Each application handles this individually through code. All of the ones you've named already do this, so something has probably gone wrong with your system.

Comment: Are you asserting that Gnome is *not* grabbing system keystrokes from unaware applications?  "Grab keyboard" mode works correctly in my gnome-aware applications, but this is not what I'm trying to address.